# Visual Studio 2017 install fails due to Microsoft.DiagnosticsHub.KB2882822 error

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

anybody an idea why this might fail? VS2017 installation stops with that error in the log. I had similar issue with VS2017 RC builds.

```
Package 'Microsoft.DiagnosticsHub.KB2882822.Win7,version=15.0.25904.2,chip=x64' failed to install. Return code: 0, Details: Invalid source and/or destination paths
```

Comment: This happened to me too when I tried to install VS2017 RC Community.  My specific errors in the dd_setup_2016_11_17102006_errors.log file were:[0bc8:0008][2016-11-17T10:40:21] Invalid source and/or destination paths
[0bc8:0008][2016-11-17T10:40:21] Package 'Microsoft.DiagnosticsHub.KB2882822.Win7,version=15.0.25904.2,chip=x64' failed to install. Return code: 0, Details: Invalid source and/or destination paths.   I hope someone chimes in with a solution.

Comment: This issue seem similar to https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/371/cant-install-preview-4-with-error-windows-7-sp1-re.html  but I tried the suggestions there and it didn't work for me.

Comment: I have the same problem with VS Enterprise 2017 RC

Answer (score 0):

One possible reason this could occur is that antivirus programs are being configured to be more aggressive at blocking executable files running from a temp directory.  The installation of this component executes DISM.EXE which in turn executes DISMHOST.EXE from the user APPDATA\LOCAL\TEMP folder.

The quickest way to confirm this is to temporarily disable your antivirus program.  The safer way to confirm this would be to review your antivirus program configuration and corresponding log files.

Answer (score -1):

The issue is most likely that the windows username has a space in it and when one portion of the installer wants access to a temp folder under the user profile directory it throws an error due to a bug because it can't handle the space in the username. (Shout out to Wong Man Wei who identified the root cause!)

A work around, is to create a new user on the machine that does not have a space in the name. Then run the installer again and repair the existing install that was done from the other user and the repair will work successfully since it has access to a temp directory under this user that has no space in the name.

Now once the repair is successful you can delete this user account and go back to using the one with the space in it.